# sfml server will not connect

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to learn sfml, the below code is not my own. At a later time i will write my own. For now i need to know why the connection in not connecting to my real ip, but works when i use my local ip.

here is my code

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<SFML/Network.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctime>

int main()
{
    sf::IpAddress ip = "142.187.215.01"; // works with 127.0.0.1 or sf::IpAddress::localhost
    std::cout << ip;
    sf::TcpSocket socket; 
    char connectionType;
    std::string text = "";
    char buffer[2000], mode = 'r';
    std::size_t received;

    std::cout << "Enter (s) for Server, Enter (c) for Client: "; 
    std::cin >> connectionType;

    if(connectionType == 's')
    {
        sf::TcpListener listener;
        listener.listen(2000);
        listener.accept(socket);
        text += "Server";
        mode = 's';
    }
    else if(connectionType == 'c')
    {
        socket.connect(ip, 2000);
        text += "Client";
    }

    socket.send(text.c_str(), text.length() + 1);
    socket.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), received);

    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

    bool done = false; 

    while(!done)
    {
        if(mode == 's')
        {
            std::getline(std::cin, text);
            socket.send(text.c_str(), text.length() + 1);
            mode = 'r';
        }
        else if(mode == 'r')
        {
            socket.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), received); 
            if(received > 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << std::endl; 
                mode = 's';
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If you are running a firewall check it's settings. If the IP address you are connecting to is your router check to make sure the port is being forwarded. If the IP address is your machine make sure it hasn't changed due to things like the DHCP lease expiring.

Comment: Obviously i disabled my firewall and i have tried port forwarding the port 2000. Still no luck. My ip address is correct.

Comment: _"Obviously i disabled my firewall"_ - It's only obvious if the information is included in your question.

Comment: Its obvious i ran through the basic steps before asking a question.

Comment: 1) Make sure your test client connects locally on your PC: DONE.  2) Make sure your firewall allows port 2000: DONE.  3) Make sure your *server's* firewall allows connections on port 2000. Failing all else: 4) check the error logs and router logs on your server, and 5) try a network trace with Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org.

Comment: I had a similar problem. If you are on Windows, go to control panel -> window firewall -> advanced settings -> inbound rules. Make sure that your .exe is allowed through the windows firewall on the protocols you use. Once again, this only works on windows.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think you cannot connect to your own PC by using a non-local IP address. Try to connect to a friend running this exact code (you as the server, him as the client) and I'm pretty sure it would work.